# Getting inappropriate bounding of path in safari

Tags: d3.js, svg, safari

Actually, I want to make a selection box over the path.

To create the box I need to find the actual boundings of that path but
I'm getting inappropriate boundings on safari only. where I'm using
`getScreenCTM()` function of `d3.select("path").node()`. I also tried
with the `getBBox()` function but this giving the wrong result after
zooming or the panning the main `SVG`.

```js
let section  = d3.select("path");
d3.select("#boundingClientRect").on("click", () => {
 let bounding = section.node().getBoundingClientRect();
  d3.select('rect').remove()
  d3.select("svg").append('rect')
    .attr('x', bounding.top)
    .attr('y', bounding.left)
    .attr('fill', '#ff45455a')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('width', bounding.width)
    .attr('height', bounding.height)
  
})

d3.select("#screenCTM").on("click", () => {
 let bounding = section.node().getBoundingClientRect();
  let screenCTM = section.node().getScreenCTM();
  Object.defineProperty(bounding, 'bottom', {
    value: (bounding.top - section.node().getScreenCTM().f + section.node().getCTM().f) + bounding.height
  });
  Object.defineProperty(bounding, 'top', {
    value: (bounding.top - section.node().getScreenCTM().f + section.node().getCTM().f)
  });
  d3.select('rect').remove()
  d3.select("svg").append('rect')
    .attr('x', bounding.top)
    .attr('y', bounding.left)
    .attr('fill', '#ff45455a')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('width', Math.abs(bounding.right - bounding.left))
    .attr('height', Math.abs(bounding.top - bounding.bottom))
  
})
```

```css
#tool{
  position:fixed;
  left:20px;
  top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="tool">
<button id="boundingClientRect" >
getBoundingClientRect
</button>
<button id="screenCTM" >
getScreenCTM
</button>
</div>
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
<path class="section" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#dddddd" stroke="#aaaaaa" stroke-width="1" d="M 288.50631321538214 239.24248598815532 L 288.50631321538214 239.24248598815532 L 801.3579069918218 228.30165198759127 L 823.2395749929499 520.9689615026793 L 280.3006877149591 527.8069827530319  Z">  
</path>
</svg>
```

Could you help me to sort this out?

Comment: Please post your code here so that other users can replicate and troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Hello, @ialarmedalien https://jsfiddle.net/y50dft6j/6/ here you can find the code base.

Comment: Please add your code INLINE in your question, so it doesn't get link-rot. I manually copy and pasted - and it no longer works - so please fix inline.

Comment: Michael Mullany, how the getScreenCTM is working to get the bounding of the path, but this is not working on the safari browser.